# Paragraph extending but not extending it's parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site in which there is a show more button which is attached to the following JQuery code:

```
jQuery(function($){
$("#experience a").bind("click touchstart", function() {
    $("#experience p").css('display','block');
});
});
```

Some visual aid:

[image]

The button you see changes the display value of some p tags to display block.

So the p tags start as `display:none;` and are given `style="display:block;"`

[image]

As you can see the text extends and pushes the whole section down.

Occasionally this happens:

[image]

The only element I can see that is maybe an issue are some empty p tags but would this really cause text to just overgrow its' natural container.

Comment: clear your floats, if you have bootstrap use the clearfix class

Comment: So what actually causes this odd behaviour?